# JSON post works in IE, not in FF

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

I have an asp.net MVC app.  One of the forms posts json data to a public method (not an action, perhaps it will be later) on the controller.  This works great in IE 8.  However, it does not work in Firefox 3.5.

The view is a list of jquery sortable objects inside of a form.  Here is a stripped down version of the form:

```
<form class="cmxform" id="UserForm" method="post" action="/Home/Index"> 
//...the <li> objects that are sortable
<input type="submit" value="Save Changes" onclick="SaveLinks();" />
</form>
```

Here is the javascript  to fire when the button is clicked.  /Home/ProcessLinks is a public method in the controller, and Visible and Invisible is a parameter being passed to the method:

```
 function SaveLinks() {
        var VisibleList = document.getElementById('sortable1');
        var InvsibleList = document.getElementById('sortable2');

        for (var i = 0; i < VisibleList.childNodes.length; i++) {
            var link = {};
            link.id = VisibleList.childNodes[i].childNodes[1].innerText;
            link.title = VisibleList.childNodes[i].childNodes[2].innerText;
            link.description = VisibleList.childNodes[i].childNodes[3].innerText;
            link.url = VisibleList.childNodes[i].childNodes[4].innerText;
            link.order = i + 1;

            $.post("/Home/ProcessLinks/Visible", $.toJSON(link), function(data, testStatus) {
                /*This is where the user can be notified that the item was saved successfully*/
                //alert(link.id + " has been updated");
                window.location.reload();
            }, "text");
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < InvsibleList.childNodes.length; i++) {
            var link = {};
            link.id = InvsibleList.childNodes[i].childNodes[1].innerText;
            link.title = InvsibleList.childNodes[i].childNodes[2].innerText;
            link.description = InvsibleList.childNodes[i].childNodes[3].innerText;
            link.url = InvsibleList.childNodes[i].childNodes[4].innerText;
            link.order = i + 1;

            $.post("/Home/ProcessLinks/Invisible", $.toJSON(link), function(data, testStatus) {
                /*This is where the user can be notified that the item was saved successfully*/
                //alert(link.id + " has been updated");
                window.location.reload();
            }, "text");
        }
    }
```

It is my belief that the above method does not get triggered when in Firefox, as the breakpoints I place with Firebug don't get hit.

For fun, here is my serverside function:

```
    public string ProcessLinks(string id)
    {
        string Type = id;
        string json = Request.Form[0];

        var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(JsonObject));
        var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(json));
        JsonObject item = (JsonObject)serializer.ReadObject(memoryStream);
        memoryStream.Close();

        return "hello";
    }
```

And my custom class JsonObject:

```
[DataContract]
public class JsonObject
{
        [DataMember]
        internal int id { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        internal string title { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        internal string description { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        internal string order { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        internal string url { get; set; }
}
```

Do you have any idea what I'm doing wrong?  I can't seem to nail it down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:** 
after looking at the code you uploaded I removed the `<input type="submit...` button from the form and added a `button` tag outside the form like this:

```
</form>
<button onclick="SaveLinks();">Save Changes</button>
```

After click this I got an error in FireFox:

```
"VisibleList.childNodes[i].childNodes[1] is undefined"
```

To correct this I took the code from jerjer's answer ( i had to modify it a bit ) and came up with the following `SaveLinks()` method that works in FF.

```
function SaveLinks() {
    $('#sortable1 li').each(function(i, item) {
        var divs = $('div:not(.imagecontainer)', this);

        var link = {
            id: $(divs[0]).text(),
            title: $(divs[1]).text(),
            description: $(divs[2]).text(),
            url: $(divs[3]).text(),
            order: i + 1
        };

        $.post("/Home/ProcessLinks/Visible", $.toJSON(link), function(data, testStatus) {
            /*This is where the user can be notified that the item was saved successfully*/
            alert(link.id + " has been updated");
            //window.location.reload();
        }, "text");
    });

    $('#sortable2 li').each(function(i, item) {
        var divs = $('div:not(.imagecontainer)', this);

        var link = {
            id: $(divs[0]).text(),
            title: $(divs[1]).text(),
            description: $(divs[2]).text(),
            url: $(divs[3]).text(),
            order: i + 1
        };

        $.post("/Home/ProcessLinks/Invisible", $.toJSON(link), function(data, testStatus) {
            /*This is where the user can be notified that the item was saved successfully*/
            alert(link.id + " has been updated");
            //window.location.reload();
        }, "text");
    });
    return false;
}
```

Comment: The reason I post each object rather than the list order is because properties of the objects may be edited before posted.  I will refactor once I get this proof of concept working

Comment: Yes, it is working.  I will upload a zip file of the solution for you if you wish to see what I'm doing.

Comment: Thanks Jared, that works beautifully.  I do see what my problem was in the jquery, including inexperience :)     I didn't even think about the input type=submit being an issue!

Answer (score 4):

Firefox does not support `innerText`. Use `innerHTML` instead.

Another possible reason is the following HTML:

```
<div>
    <span>foo</span>
    <span>bar</span>
</div>
```

will have the following structure in IE

```
div
   |---span(childNode[0])
   |       |
   |       '---text---foo
   |
   '---span(childNode[1])
           |
           '---text---bar
```

while in all other browsers including firefox it will have the following structure:

```
div
   |---text(childNode[0])---newline and tabs
   |
   |---span(childNode[1])
   |       |
   |       '---text---foo
   |
   |---text(childNode[2])---newline and tabs
   |
   '---span(childNode[3])
           |
           '---text---bar
```

This ridiculous behavior is mandated by the W3C spec. So IE is technically **wrong** here.

Now, I notice in your code you make assumptions about childNode indexing without checking `element.nodeName`. That could be where the problem lies.

Comment: although innerHTML too is not a part of the W3C DOM specification

Comment: Done.  The app still doesn't work as I don't believe it even gets to that function in Firefox.

Comment: Regarding your edit:  I'm fairly certain my problem is the function doesn't even get triggered when I use Firefox.  Breakpoints I set in Firebug do not get hit.  If the childNode indexing is the problem here then my breakpoints are being skipped for some reason

Comment: I echo what Jared said, nice explanation.  I will look into this but I feel while that may be _an_ issue, it is not the _current_ issue

Comment: Hmm.. in that case it's strange indeed. I can't see anything else wrong with your code. What's your DOCTYPE? Also try deleting the body of SaveLinks and replace it with an alert to see that gets triggered.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using jquery, you might as well use the jquery's shorthand for getting/setting text/html.

for instance getting text content:

```
link.id = $(VisibleList.childNodes[i].childNodes[1]).text();
link.title = $(VisibleList.childNodes[i].childNodes[2]).text();
link.description = $(VisibleList.childNodes[i].childNodes[3]).text();
link.url = $(VisibleList.childNodes[i].childNodes[4]).text();
link.order = i + 1;
```

getting html content:

```
link.id = $(VisibleList.childNodes[i].childNodes[1]).html();
link.title = $(VisibleList.childNodes[i].childNodes[2]).html();
link.description = $(VisibleList.childNodes[i].childNodes[3]).html();
link.url = $(VisibleList.childNodes[i].childNodes[4]).html();
link.order = i + 1;
```

This is the jquery equivalent:

```
$('#sortable1 li').each(function(){
    var $li = $(this);   
    var link = {};
    link.id = $li.children(1).text();
    link.title =$li.children(2).text();
    link.description = $li.children(3).text();
    link.url = $li.children(4).text();
    link.order = i + 1;

    $.post("/Home/ProcessLinks/Visible", $.toJSON(link), function(data, testStatus) {
        /*This is where the user can be notified that the item was saved successfully*/
        //alert(link.id + " has been updated");
        window.location.reload();
    }, "text");
});
```